# htaccess RewriteRule not working - (404 error) from server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my URL from this:

```
http://www.example.com/admin/index.php?id=title
```

to:

```
http://www.example.com/admin/title
```

I'm using this code in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /admin/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But then when I try out rewritten URL's i get a 404 error from my server. What is the mistake I'm making? The .htaccess is in a subfolder called admin and the rewrite rule should only work for that folder.

Comment: Yes. That's how it's set up.

Comment: You are rewriting `/admin/title.html` and not `admin/title`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `.htaccess` should be placed inside the folder `admin` that must be inside your root folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The 2 conditions make sure we are not redirecting an existent file or folder and rule tells we want to extract anything not a `/` and use as the ID.

The `RewriteBase` tell us your parent folder is `admin` and as such we work from there and onwards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer with explanation! Did not know about RewriteBase.

Comment: @FrankKluytmans glad it worked for you and you learned something new :)